# index number of nested lapply

Tags: r, nested, lapply

I'm trying to understand how to access the outer iteration index of a nested lapply function over 2 lists.

dummy case: lets say i have a list of 2 items here, and on of 3 items and use a nested lapply to make variables item1_x, item1_y, item1_z etc. 
In the code i'm working on I tried to access the iteration indices which I can do for the inner lapply with parent.frame()$i[], but how to also access the outer iteration index?

Goal: I want to print 1, 2 as the code goes through the outer lapply 
                print 1, 2, 3 as the code goes through the inner lapply
    and thus be able to also print outer index times inner index, i,e 1,2,3,4,5,6

I was looking for a similar code piece as parent.frame()$i[] to access the outer iteration index (if that exists), also to better understand how that works, but honestly any other solution will be good of course

```
mylist <- c("item1", "item2")

  lapply(mylist, function(y) {
         lapply(c("x", "y", "z"), function(x) {
            print(parent.frame()$i[])
### access index number of outer lapply here somehow. 
###   index 1 * index 2 should be giving a print(...) of 1:6 than...

        })})
```

Comment: Could you give a more clear example of what you want the output of the function to be? I don't understand what the goal is here.

Comment: Pseudo code is rarely helpful for us. Develop an actual reproducible example.

Comment: Parfait, this code is perfectly reproducable. The only difference between this and my real code is the name of the mylist and its content, and inside the lapply loop i am trying to build shiny UI buttons that will grab a label from a list of 6 names, hence i'm looking for a way to get the output 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 from output 1,2 (outer lapply) x 1,2,3 (inner) 
But adding shiny code to this question would have made it extremely unnecessary overly complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches

Using `mapply`

```
mapply(function(y, z) {
                lapply(c("x", "y", "z"), function(x) {
                                            print(paste(y, x))
                                            print(z)
                                        })
        }, 
        mylist, 
        seq_along(mylist))
```

Or only `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(mylist),   function(y) {
                                lapply(c("x", "y", "z"), function(x) {
                                                            print(paste(mylist[y], x))
                                                        })
                            })
```